# Site policy for those developing weapons

Tags: discussion

What is the site policy on those who seem to be developing weapons e.g. taser, stun or lethal shock devices?

I am not referring to the development of something that is likely to injure the op or bystanders. I am referring to stuff that is designed to injure or kill. This is not preachy moralization I have a military background and have played with more of this stuff than you can imagine. The problem is that devices like this are specifically banned in some jurisdictions. The US centric view that this stuff is ok is not shared by the rest of the world. If we are seen to be assisting in its illegal development we are going to be liable despite the CYA conditions in the Ts&Cs. Especially in todays climate.

Comment: To add to Olin's answer, I'd say if you feel you can word your concerns in a polite manner, you are always free to place a comment, and if you are very, very worried for decent reasons, it is possible to flag a question - sparingly.

Comment: @Asmyldof  "sparingly" Yes hint taken, still learning the system here.

Comment: See also: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/do-we-have-any-guidelines-toward-weapons-design

Comment: @Dim, thanks your answer to that was clear well thought out and relevant.

Answer (score 0):

As long as someone isn't asking for help doing something clearly illegal, there should be no issue.  Tasers and the like are legitimate products, and somebody somewhere has to design them.  There is no reason they shouldn't be able to come here for help.

That said, everyone that answers here is a volunteer and in no way obligated to help.  If you personally object to a project on moral grounds, don't answer.  However, recognize that others may consider it totally legitimate, and getting in their way just because you object is not acceptable.

This site is about electrical engineering.  Preachy moralizations are off topic here.